# Difference between $\left \langle x \right \rangle$ and $\left \langle \hat{x} \right \rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, notation

I am having a difficult time understanding the meaning of the expected value of the operator and the difference between that and the expected value of the physical quantity.

If I take for example the expected value of the position, it is given by:

$$\left \langle x \right \rangle=\int \Psi ^{\star }.x.\Psi dx$$

Here the full stop "$.$" means multiplication.
I am following this [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YymnLDIrKuU&list=PL65jGfVh1ilueHVVsuCxNXoxrLI3OZAPI&index=10&ab_channel=BrantCarlson) and I am confused about how did he come up with the expected value of the operators.

Is the following analysis correct or not? what am I missing?

$$\left [ x. \right ]=\hat{x}$$

$$\left \langle x \right \rangle=\int \Psi ^{\star }.x.\Psi dx=\int \Psi ^{\star }.\left [x.  \right ]\Psi=\int \Psi ^{\star }.\hat{x}\Psi=\left \langle \hat{x} \right \rangle$$

Answer (score 2):

The hat on $x$ represents the fact that it's not the variable but an operator. Sometimes authors use the capital letter $X$ to show that they mean operator (Position operator here). While $x$ is an eigenvalue of operator $X$. Or outside quantum mechanics simply a variable for position.

The expectation value of some physical observable $\Omega$ in-state $|\psi\rangle $ given by
$$\langle \Omega\rangle =\langle \psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle $$

---

Consider the position operator $X$, in this case,
$$\langle X\rangle =\langle \psi|X|\psi\rangle =\int \int dx\ dx'\ \langle\psi|x\rangle \langle x|X|x'\rangle \langle x'|\psi\rangle =\int \int dx\ dx' \psi^*(x)x'\delta(x-x')\psi(x') $$
Or
$$\langle  X\rangle =\int dx\ \psi^*(x) x\psi(x)=\int dx\ x |\psi(x)|^2 $$
which is simply the expectation of variable $x$ with probability distribution given by $|\psi(x)|^2$ (postulate of quantum mechanics).

Comment: Actually I think you should have $\langle \Omega\rangle=\langle \psi\vert \hat\Omega\vert\psi\rangle$ since on the right you have the action of an operator on a state, and subsequent projection, with the result that on the left you have a generally complex number.